# SQL Procedure Update Table based on SUM of values from Two Other Tables

Tags: sql, procedure, subquery

I have three tables: 
ForecastAccuracy - I want to update this table column ThreeMonthForecast
tbl_Master - I want to get the SUM by Customer Account
tbl_new_prod - I want to get the SUM by Customer Account
I want the total of SUM from the two Tables to Update the [3] column in Forecast Accuracy. The code below updates it with SUM from tbl_Master correctly. I do not know how to incorporate the third table within this code without doing another update. Is there a better way to go about it?

```
UPDATE m
SET m.ThreeMonthForecast = f.valsum
FROM ForecastAccuracy m
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT [Customer Account], SUM([tbl_Master.[3]) valsum
    FROM [tbl_Master Forecast_Dollars]
    WHERE [Cycle] = @ThreeMonthCycle
    GROUP BY [Customer Account]
) f ON m.Account = f.[Customer Account]


tbl_Master

Account      Cycle      [3]
123456       01-14      100.00
654321       01/14      500.00

tbl_new_prod

Account      Cycle      [3]
123456       01-14      300.00
654321       01/14      600.00

tbl_ForecastAccuracy

Account      Cycle      ThreeMonthForecast
123456       01-14      400.00  <--- Sum of Master[3] + Product[3]
654321       01/14      1100.00 <--- Sum of Master[3] + Product[3]
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CTE wrapped around your current from clause with another grouping / calculation.

I have not tested this, so it is unlikely to even parse correctly, but hopefully it will help you in the right direction.

The theory is you have the values needed for the final calculation within the CTE, so you would apply the final grouping and calculation in your update.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    FROM ForecastAccuracy m
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT [Customer Account], SUM([tbl_Master.[3]) valsum
        FROM [tbl_Master Forecast_Dollars]
        WHERE [Cycle] = @ThreeMonthCycle
        GROUP BY [Customer Account]
    ) f ON m.Account = f.[Customer Account]
)
UPDATE m
SET m.ThreeMonthForecast = SUM(CTE.valsum)
FROM CTE
GROUP BY [Customer Account]
```